# Telegram bot in python shows time out error

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm getting the following error when i run the telegram code

```
'''
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because 
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of 
time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond  '''
```

I've run this exact same code a month ago it was working fine.
This is my code:

```
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token="My API-KEY"
    bot_chatID="bot ID"
    send_text= "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + 
               "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + bot_chatID + 
               "&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=" + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)
    return response.json()

telegram_bot_sendtext("hello how do you do")
```